# How to send the notifications through my message after reminder task finished in back end

Tags: java, android, notifications

In my back end(java) i have a code for reminder job. After finishing the reminder job task i need to send the notification message to the users those who are added to the reminder functionality.We finished the coding for back end.I don't know how to add this functionality to front end(android studio)..I need to add this notification message in my chat window.Please tell me the solution for this.

This is my controller

```
public class ReminderTask implements Task {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ReminderTask.class);

    @Autowired
    private SendReminderMessageProcess sendReminderMessageProcessImpl;

    /**
     * @see com.ringee.web.job.Task#StartJob()
     * @param
     * @throws
     */
    @Override
    public void StartJob() {
        log.info("inside the reminder task");
        Date todaysDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        log.info(" todays date ==== " + todaysDate);
        try {
            // starting reminder job
            SchedulerData schedulerData = sendReminderMessageProcessImpl.startJob();

            sendReminderMessageProcessImpl.extractReminderDaysData(schedulerData);

            sendReminderMessageProcessImpl.endJob(schedulerData);

        } catch (UserServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

How to add notification message in group chat activity after finishing reminder job in back end....Please help me to find out

Answer (score 1):

What i think you should do is keep your data in a local DB , update your values along with a flag that gives you the current status of your notification[Say 0-unread , 1-read] update these flags with a query to your DB, once you are done with that ;
Check the status in onCreate() method of your activity, or wherever you are loading your activity/your chat list and mark your unread/ to be notified elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What i am asking is,i have reminder job code in backend...After finishing that task i need to send notification message to users....I dont know how to call this(use this )from back end to front end

Comment: So do you mean you need to send a message back to the calling Activity?

Comment: yes......i need to send a notification to user...so i need cal front end from back end

Comment: Ok then send a context of your activity to the service, and call a function from the calling activity once your service has completed its execution , so for example you use an Interface with some method that the activity implements send a response to that method.

Comment: can u please add some example

Comment: okay, so send context  of your calling activity to ReminderTask  constructor[i.e, from where you trigger the ReminderTak] and with refrence to that context call whichever method you want to from that activity context, say : Activity has a method callMeBack(token) , so from your ReminderTask call context.callMeBack(int token);

Comment: is it possible...Because my activity code is in front end and my reminder task code is in back end?????